# Google Oauth2 giving "redirect_uri_mismatch" error in production when redirect uri setup correctly

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I have google oauth set up in a react project. It was working fine in development, locally. Once i promoted the oauth client to "production" and modified the JS origin and redirect URIs to production values, yet it gives this error

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's
> OAuth 2.0 policy.
>
> If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google
> Cloud Console. Request details:
> redirect_uri=http://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback
> Related developer documentation

These are the authorized redirect URIs within google cloud console:

- https://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback
- https://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback/
- https://www.super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback
- https://www.super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback/

As you can see, there are no authorized uri's with an `HTTP` schema. Theyre not even allowed in production mode. So im not sure where this is coming from, because the server is `HTTPS`

server:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

the redirect uri must exactly match the one you are adding to Google developer console

If you check the error message your app is running with

```
http://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback
```

All the ones you have added are https

May i suggest fixing your app so that it runs https.  I dont think that you will be able to add http as a production redirect uri endpoint.

## documentation

[Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#obtainingaccesstokens)

[image]

[authorization-errors-redirect-uri-mismatch](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#authorization-errors-redirect-uri-mismatch)

[image]

## Node.js

I dont know enough about react.js but with node you should be able to do something like this

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
```

Comment: my server runs HTTPS. its accessed by the client through HTTPS

Comment: your server may run HTTPS but your code is not running HTTPS The redirect URI your app is sending is redirect_uri=http: //super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback   Fix your code.  Maybe something like this  [How to configure HTTPS in a React app on localhost](https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-configure-https-localhost/)

Comment: @DalmTo what do you mean "code is not running HTTPS"? the redirect uri is not set in code

Comment: No its not but the client library is setting it, and it can see that your app has not been configured to run https.   You need to set up your application to run https, not the server this is something in your code.   There is a way to route reactJS to be running https you just havent done it.

Comment: @DalmTo the link you posted is for development? This web client & server is live in production. the oauth client settings in google console are also set to production.

Comment: Sorry i can not tell you how to configur your application to run https.  This question is about the redirect uri.   As stated the Redirect uri must exactly match the one that your application is sending.  Your application is sending as HTTP. This is not problem to configure in as a redirect uri in production.   You must configure your application to run https if you want to run it in production.  May is suggest that you ask another question "How to run ReactJS as HTTPS?"

Comment: Alternatively you could google it there are a lot of articles on it [Why You Should Use HTTPS In React App Production](https://www.thesharpener.net/how-to-use-https-in-your-react-app-production/)  it seams to have something to do with configuring the cert.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `redirect_uri` on the client side (React side) is set to http://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback

Change the `redirect_uri` on the client side from (http) http://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback to (https) https://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (MERN + passport.js), i had a configuration that looked like:

```
const googleOptions = {
  clientID: config.google.id,
  clientSecret: config.google.secret,
  passReqToCallback: true,
  callbackURL: '/v1/auth/google/callback',
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
};
```

Even though the server, the client && the configuration of the oauth client within google api console were all in production with everything setup for `https`, for some reason, the callbackURL kept firing with google oauth as `http://my-domain.com/v1/auth/google/callback`

so this fix may be hacky, but it did fix my oauth issues:

```
//Google Strategy
const googleOptions = {
  clientID: config.google.id,
  clientSecret: config.google.secret,
  passReqToCallback: true,
  callbackURL: config.environment == 'production' ? 'https://super-server.herokuapp.com/v1/auth/google/callback' : '/v1/auth/google/callback',
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
};
```